# Mutual Friends PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, inner-join

So usually I wouldn't ask from help like this, so this is a first. But I've been racking my brains for two days now over a query that is most likely simple.

I'm wanting to get the count and the actual users printed out that our mutual to each other just like facebook.

My tables are as follows.

Friends
id  |  user1_id  | user2_id | status

User
id | first | last

So I grasp the simple idea behind it. if I'm friends with someone, and they're also friends with that person that person becomes a mutual friend.

I've tried the below with no real results and tried so many other examples offline and to put it frank I don't understand inner-joins as I use them rarely so if someone could come up with something and possibly explain each part that may help me and others work out something for the future.

My session id is under $user1_id and user 2 is under $user2_id which are all sanitized against MYSQLI injection if this helps!

Thank you to anyone that can help me.

```
 $mutual_friends = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
SELECT user.id
FROM user
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT friends.user1_id, friends.user2_id, friends.status
    FROM friends 
    WHERE friends.user1_id = '$user1_id' AND friends.status = 2 
      AND friends.user2_id = user.id
  )
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT friends.user1_id, friends.user2_id, friends.status
    FROM friends 
    WHERE friends.user1_id = '$user2_id' AND friends.status = 2 
      AND friends.user2_id = user.id
  )
");
$mutualfriend=mysqli_fetch_array($mutual_friends);
$mutualfriendcount=mysqli_num_rows($mutual_friends);
The mutual friend count by number
echo"".$mutualfriendcount.";

var_dump($mutual_friends );
while($mutualfriend=mysqli_fetch_array($mutual_friends)){

The list of users by name and id 

}
```

Comment: I think you need a recursive function that gets the friends of the user sent as parameter and you call it for each of your friends, and their friend's friends etc.

Comment: Such as :

`$user_core  = new user_core;
$check = $user_core->check_friends();`

Comment: Do the user id columns in the table have a numerical or a character data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mutual_friends = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
SELECT     user.user_id,
           user.first,
           user.last
FROM       user
INNER JOIN friends as friends1
       ON  friends1.user2_id = user.id
       AND friends1.user1_id = " . $user1_id . "
       AND friends1.status = 2
INNER JOIN friends as friends2
       ON  friends2.user2_id = user_id
       AND friends2.user1_id = " . $user2_id . "
       AND friends2.status = 2
");
```

Explanation:

First of all, your user_id columns are numerical, so you should not wrap their 
values in quotes.

`SELECT ... FROM user` has no secrets, it select all users.

Then the `INNER JOIN` with `friends` will find those records in `friends` that have 
the `user1_id` set to your connected user and express a friendship with the user record it is joined to.
Now if there is no such record in `friends`, then the `user` record is filtered away from the result set.
So in essence after the first `INNER JOIN` we are left with user records that correspond 
to the friends of the connected user.

Then the second `INNER JOIN` again tries to find friends, but with one difference. This
time `user1_id` must match with the given `$user2_id`. So this is limited to friends 
of user #2. Now some of these friends were already filtered out from the result set
after the first `INNER JOIN` was applied, so now we only reduce the result set further
by taking out the users that are not friends of user #2.

And that gives the desired end result.

Comment: I used your query and got this in var dump

`object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) } `

But I'm not getting any names or ids printed out and I have 1 mutual friend added with another so there should be one at least.

Comment: Does it matter if I go into a separate page to see them with mutualfriends.php?user2_id=83

Comment: Show us your data, so we can check ourselves. Are you sure the status of all friendships is 2 in your data? Also, what is the data type of the user_id field in your database. If it is numeric then you should not put quotes around the user id in the SQL.

Comment: Id's in both fields are INT(11). 
The status of friends being friends is 2..1 is pending and 0 is not friends.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer, and included the surrounding PHP statement.

Comment: Indeed this is working perfectly on getting the users number count.. Just need to sit and work out how to print the users list out now but I will attempt that myself. Thanks so much for your help and your time and explanation. Really helped me understand it in depth.